# Notepad++ regex code to extract end of line

Tags: regex, notepad++

i have a source code that i need to capture. the whole file is of one line but i am not able to capture the data that i require.

```
allow=ok&secret=4326dwsaddsafsd286435dsfs754
```

now i need to capture this data 4326dwsaddsafsd286435dsfs754 which changes everytime. it contains mixed a-z and 0-9, total lenght 40 letters

i tried using Left and Right selectors by using "secret=" on left but since the source ends at the end of the value, i dont have any thing to put in right selector.

so i need to know how can i capture this data? is there any regex cmd that can let me.?

thanks

Comment: Use `[?#&]secret=\K[A-Za-z0-9]+`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    `\&secret=(.*)`
and then capture the first group with $1

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
[a-z0-9]*$
```

It searches for the longest sequence of alpha-numeric characters (`[a-z0-9]*`) at the end of the string (`$`).

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/D2rSuB/1).